# Random walk on free group on two elements

Tags: probability, random-walk, free-groups

Let $F_2$ be the free group on two elements, generated by $\{a, b\}$. We perform a random walk on $F_2$, starting at the identity element $e$ and uniformly at random selecting one of $\{a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1}\}$ to append to the current walk. So e.g. there's a 1/16 probability your second step will be $\{ba^{-1}\}$, and 1/4 probability your second step will be to $\{e\}$.

My question is: what is the probability we hit $a$ before we hit $b$?

My approach has been the following. Let $x_n$ be the probability we hit $a$ before hitting $b$ when starting at a word of length $n$, the first symbol of which is neither $a$ nor $b$ (ie it can only start with $a^{-1}$ or $b^{-1}$). It's not hard to see this is well defined. We are seeking $x_0$. By conditioning on possible next steps it's not hard to get the equations:

$x_0 = 1/4 + (1/2)x_1$

$x_{n+1} = (1/4)x_n + (3/4)x_{n+2}$

Unfortunately I don't think those alone are enough to infer the value of $x_0$, which makes me think there's an extra insight I'm missing. Any ideas?

(This is taken from 123Ga in Weighing the Odds by Williams, which I've been working through in self study)

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, the probability of hitting $a$ before we hit $b$ is the same as the probability of hitting $b$ before we hit $a$. So, what is the probability of never hitting either element?

Comment: I get your suggestion: if we knew the probability p of never hitting either element, we could use 1 = 2x + p. But seems like the problem of calculating p gives me the same issue - trying to calculate the complementary probability of hitting at least one of $a$ or $b$ I get the same equations as in the body of my question, but with $x_0 = 1/2 + (1/2)x_1$